# How can i insert row into table sqlalchemy object?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i have table object that its name is tags and i don't know how to insert new row into it

this is my table object :

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('Post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

i tried to use this query for test :

```
db.session.add(tags(
        post_id = 1,
        tag_id = 2
))
```

But I encountered this error :

```
TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A many-to-many relationship adds an association table between the two models.

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
        db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
        db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'), primary_key=True)
    )
    
class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Now you can insert data into the table:

```
>>> page = Page()
>>> tag = Tag()
>>> page.tags.append(tag)
>>> db.session.add(page)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Read [this](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) for more information.

Answer (score 18):

I encourage you to use SQLAlchemy ORM approach. In your case it would be something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Tags(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    tag_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'), primary_key=True)


session.add(Tags(tag_id=1, post_id=2))
session.commit()
```

Check SQLAlchemy site, they have great docs, recipes and examples!

Comment: [Context of question](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: if a table already exists, how do you retrieve it as an object rather than having to create a class? can that be done?

Answer (score 18):

[An actual answer](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions) for the stated question, you need to get an `Insert` object from the table:

```
ins = tags.insert().values(post_id=1, tag_id=2)
db.engine.execute(ins)
```

Comment: `Engine.execute()` is getting removed in 2.0. The SQLAlchemy docs suggest doing `Connection.execute()` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute